# Angular recursive function for nested objects in array

Tags: javascript, angular, object, ionic-framework, nested

I am building a custom filter pipe for the following structure

```
[
    {
        "client": {
            "name": "DJASLDJSAKL"
        }, 
        "job_status": {
            "name": "Scheduled"
        }, 
        "descriptor": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit lacinia quam, ultrices leo interdum senectus integer ultricies venenatis nisl libero, et tellus nec litora volutpat proin duis neque. \r\n\r\nUt metus ac enim mauris malesuada bibendum lectus tincidunt nascetur phasellus, tristique quam libero purus dapibus nisl ultricies urna. \r\n\r\nNisl cubilia donec imperdiet nisi tempus venenatis cras egestas, duis senectus at orci ad porttitor in, magnis suspendisse sem ullamcorper neque tincidunt etiam.\r\n\r\nLitora pulvinar viverra et velit felis massa commodo etiam la.\r\n", 
        "duracion": {
            "text": "00:00:00" 
        }, 
        "tech": {
            "eta_promise_date": "Nov 20 2019 03:05:00:PM"
        }, 
        "siteAddress": "537 West Thomas Drive Rolling Meadows, IL 60008"
    }
]
```

I first made a function that works only at first level, or top level. Searching I have like an idea, but at the same time I'm kind of lost, this is the method in which I'm working

```
  findObject(obj, searchTerm){
   Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
     //let r = RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi').test(obj[key]);
     if(obj === searchTerm){
       console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${obj[key]}`);
       if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
         this.findObject(obj[key], searchTerm);
       }
       return null;
     }return null;

   });
  }
```

But I'm getting an infinite loop at the moment

**EDIT** Adding the view section

```
    <ion-list *ngFor="let order of workOrders | filtro: searchTerm">
      <ion-item *ngFor = "let location of order.site" (click)="showOrderLocation(order)">
        <ion-icon name="pin" item-start [ngStyle]="{'color':order.job_status.color}"></ion-icon>
         <h4>{{order.code}}</h4><br>
         <p>{{order.job_status.name}}</p><br>
         <small>ETA: {{order.etaPromise}}</small><br>
         <small>Deadline: {{this.relativeDate(this.utcToLocalTime(order.tech.eta_promise_date))}}</small><br>
         <p>{{order.descriptor}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Is the first parameter of `findObject` really an object (since it's named `obj`) or the above specified array and how would a typically search term look like?

Comment: recursion issues aside, don't build a recursive filtering pipe. the performance will be abysmal.

Comment: @uminder sorry, yes, it is the specified array, the `searchTerm` it's a normal string, like "something"

Comment: I found this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52692849/7093453) and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursion function is a little messy. The `findObject` function should return a `boolean` depending on whether or not a property of the object matches the `searchTerm`.

It's a bad idea to use `Object.keys(obj).forEach` to iterate over the values because it prevents you from breaking out of the recursion, so use a simple for loop instead. In your case there are two cases in which you want to break out of the recursion: if the string property contains the `searchTerm` or if a nested object matches the `searchTerm`.

```
findObject(obj, searchTerm){
  let pattern = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi');
  const values = Object.values(obj)

  for (let value of values) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      // if value i a string, check if it matches!
      if (pattern.test(value)) {
        // match!
        return true
      }
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      // use recursion to check if nested object contains the search term
      const isMatch = this.findObject(value, searchTerm);
      if (isMatch) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }

  // no match, so return false
  return false
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see, sorry I did not put the view side, I want to show the results and for that I have to return the same structure, I think that maybe should I use `Object.entries`?, I edit my question adding the view section.

Comment: In that case all you need to do is return `obj` instead of `true` and `null` instead of `false`

Answer (score 2):

I woulds split the logic into two separate methods as follows:

```
const data = [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]

findObject(data: Array, searchTerm: string): Object {
   for (let obj of data) {
     if (this.contains(obj, searchTerm)) {
       return obj;
     }
   }
   return null;
}     

contains(obj: Object, searchTerm: string): boolean {
  for (let value of Object.values(obj)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      if (contains(value, searchTerm)) {
        return true;
      }
    } else if (value.includes(searchTerm)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```